# How to write quotes in PG connection string in where clause when open Postgis Raster?

Tags: python, gdal, postgis-raster

I have some rasters in PostGIS and I want to open just those which match to where clause. How can I do that? I have tried:

```
ds = gdal.Open("PG:host=<host> dbname=<dbname> table=<tablename> user=<user> password=<psswd> where='observ_date=\'2015-06-26\'::date'")
```

and some other combinations of quotes, but with no success. Everytime I got an error like this

```
ERROR 1: Error browsing database for PostGIS Raster properties : ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to date
LINE 1: ...r.alaska_mod13q1_ndvi where observ_date=2015-06-26::date gro...
```

It means that wrote quotes wrong. So how should I write quotes in where clause in PG connection string correctly?

Comment: Try using double quotes.  Like this: `''`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/1500125).

Comment: @Fezter thank you, but the same error. No quotes in a final string in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Fezter thanks a lot! `''` does not help, but dollar-quoted string does :) So for example now I can use it like this:

    `ds = gdal.Open("PG:host=<host> dbname=<dbname> table=<tablename> user=<user> password=<psswd> where='observ_date=$$'2015-06-26'$$::date'")`

and it seems to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/1500125), try using [dollar-quoted strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

So your code would look like this:

```
ds = gdal.Open("PG:host=<host> dbname=<dbname> table=<tablename> user=<user> password=<psswd> where='observ_date=$$'2015-06-26'$$::date'")
```